# How to get, ("fields") to Work in VBA-JSON

Tags: json, vba, excel, jira-rest-api

### Summary

I am trying to access the deep levels of nested JSON that comes back from the API that I am working with at the moment. Using *[VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)* through this process has been pretty easy, but I've ran into a little road block. For the most part, I've got this library to work properly, but I get an error anytime I try to grab an item that is nested in the JSON response (*further than 2 JSON levels*). I am going to submit this post, and then I'll go and gather some of the error codes that I am getting. Off the top of my head, I know that I get a [Run-time error '13'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979(v=vs.60).aspx) when I try to use the code below that doesn't work. I think (*could be wrong*) that I am smart enough to understand the type mismatch error, but I don't know how to fix it.

### This Works

```
For i = 1 To 20
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 5) = Json("issues")(i)("key")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 6) = Json("issues")(i)("id")
Next
```

#### Doesn't Work

```
For i = 1 To 20
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = Json("fields")(i)("summary")
Next
```

#### None of These Worked Either

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = Json("fields")(i)("summary")
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = Json("fields")("summary")
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = Json("issues")("fields")("summary")

ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = Json("fields")("assignee")(i)("name")
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = Json("issues")("fields")("assignee")(i)("name")
```

#### Updated with Some JSON

I edited the JSON that comes back for privacy reasons (*obviously*).

```
{
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 50,
  "total": 28,
  "issues": [ {
    "expand": "",
    "id": "94581",
    "self": "",
    "key": "",
    "fields": {
      , "assignee": {}
      , "status": {}
      , "votes": {}
      , "summary": ""
      ,
      , "issuetype": {}
      , "timespent": null,
    }
  }
  ,
  {}
  ,
  {}
  ,
  {}
  ]
}
```

According to this data structure, my code should be looking at the right place, right?

Thoughts? :)

---

*PS: Sorry if jargon is off, I'm a developer by hobby, not by job. :)*

Comment: can you give us a snippet of your Json file? It's difficult to tell if the nesting is done right without seeing the structure.  I'll admit upfront I've done very little with VBA-Json but I believe you have to specify the complete path (tree) that are trying to get to have you missed out any steps?

Comment: Try to debug: `Debug.Print TypeName(Json("fields")(i)("summary"))` and `Debug.Print TypeName(Json("fields")(i))` before assigning the value to the cell.

Comment: I can't give you the exact snippet, but I can build one with fake data. I will update the post soon @perfo. :)

Comment: Just to explain my comment a bit .... ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 5) = Json("issues")(i)("key") works but  ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = Json("fields")(i)("summary") doesn't. IS this because it should be written as ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = Json("issues")("fields")(i)("summary") ?

Comment: @omegastripes I will give that a shot and let you know what happens.

Comment: @perfo I believe I tried that combination, but no luck. I'll give it a shot again and see.

Comment: @perfo, I tried that combination again, and I got a [Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-error-5).

Comment: You're cramming half-a-dozen member access calls into a single instruction - that makes it pretty much impossible to debug. Declare more variables, split up these crazy chained default member access calls into separate instructions, inspect locals, and you'll fix your bug.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I wish I knew more about this stuff so I could do that. :( Also, this is how the VBA-JSON documentation says to grab nested data, so I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you try the line with and without the (I) in it?  I guess you have to have the windows run time scripting reference set or the first example wouldn't work. I can't really see why the line I gave you shouldn't work but I'm not an expert on it. I have to go somewhere now but if you have found the answer by tomorrow I'll have another look..  Use the for each in construct instead of the for next if you want to retrieve all the cards I don't see why this would make a difference but maybe worth a try. Good luck

Comment: @BenDains simply assign `foo1 = Json("Fields")` then `foo2 = foo1(i)` then `foo3 = foo2("summary")` and so  on. Then you can inspect the values in the debugger

Comment: @Mat'sMug will do, thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I finally got it figured out! I'll post the answer!

Comment: Great, Put it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @perfo just did, thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

#### The Problem

Nested arrays were actually the problem. The 2'nd level of JSON items were not arrays, while, "fields" was.

To solve the problem, we need to add a (i + 1) to the code.

#### Working Code Example

```
''''''''
' Loop '
''''''''

For i = 1 To 20
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 5) = Json("issues")(i)("key")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 6) = Json("issues")(i)("id")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = Json("issues")(i + 1)("fields")("summary")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 8) = Json("issues")(i + 1)("fields")("watches")("watchCount")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 9) = Json("issues")(i + 1)("fields")("workratio")
Next
```

#### Update :(

So, I got all of my code setup to run my report, and it was working, and then it randomly stops (*I watched it do this on line 16 or so*) and gives me another type mismatch error.

How were the rows 1-15 working, and then suddenly there is a type mismatch error?

lol...

Debugging now...

#### Update 2 :)

Simple mix up with the code structure, there wasn't a problem and the solution that I posted below works correctly.

Comment: I suspected it was something to do with the (I) but didn't know why.  A bit of the actual file may have cleared it up I suppose. Anyway glad you solved it...